# How is the recurrence relation of Karatsuba algorithm M(n) = 3M(n/2) for n > 1, M(1) = 1?

Tags: algorithm, integer, multiplication

The algorithm makes 3 multiplications for each of the n/2 instances. Hence shouldn't the recurrence relation be M(n) = M(n/2)+3 for n > 1, M(1) = 1 ?

Comment: 3 multiplications for each of the n/2 instances. -> Like for example 3$ for each beer you buy

Comment: "3 multiplications" means "doing multiplication three times" means "paying the cost of multiplication 3 times". If you look at code, you will see that there are 3 functions calls on instances each of which is half the size of the input. If natural language semantics become confusing, the best thing to do is look at a formalization.

Comment: Thanks everyone. That helped !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is understanding exactly how the divide and conquer happens. In [the case of the Karatsuba Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm):

> The basic step of Karatsuba's algorithm is a formula that allows one to compute the product of two large numbers x and y using three multiplications of smaller numbers, each with about half as many digits as x or y, plus some additions and digit shifts.

So, what this says is that, to solve one large problems, you recursively solve three smaller-by-half essentially-identical problems (and then do some recombining steps). The complexity recursion formula you presented in the title is exactly the formulation of this.

Comment: More precisely, should it be M(n) = 3M(n/2) + 2 + cn  Where 2 accounts for (z2*10^(2*m2))+((z1-z2-z0)*10^(m2))+(z0) ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm)  and cn is for addition and subtraction involved?

Comment: Something like that. The 2 is pretty much meaningless (if you account for stuff like that, you need to account for updating program instruction counters). It is *M(n) = 3M(n/2) + Theta(n)*, where the last term is accounted for by the addition/subtraction operations.